# How to compute overlapping time intervals between groups

Tags: r, dataframe, time, overlap

I have a dataframe with group id, start time, and end time. I would like to compute overlapped time interval between groups. Here is an example of the dataset;

```
id <- c("a","a","b","c","c")
start_time <-as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-27 09:30:00","2016-05-27 15:30:00",
                          "2016-05-27 14:30:00","2016-05-27 09:40:00","2016-05-27 15:00:00"),tz= "UTC")
end_time <-as.POSIXct(c("2016-05-27 10:30:00","2016-05-27 17:30:00",
                        "2016-05-27 16:30:00","2016-05-27 09:50:00","2016-05-27 16:00:00"),tz= "UTC")

df <- data.frame(id,start_time,end_time)
```

and the example dataframe looks like:

```
            ID             start_time           end_time
1           a        2016-05-27 09:30:00    2016-05-27 10:30:00
2           a        2016-05-27 15:30:00    2016-05-27 17:30:00
3           b        2016-05-27 14:30:00    2016-05-27 16:30:00
4           c        2016-05-27 09:40:00    2016-05-27 09:50:00
5           c        2016-05-27 15:00:00    2016-05-27 16:00:00
```

The desired result from the suggested dataframe is

```
            ID_1             ID_2        overlap
1           a                 b         0 + 60 mins
2           a                 c        10 + 0 + 0 + 30 mins
3           b                 c         0 + 60 mins
```

The last column does not have to show all the cases. It is just to help your understand. Would there be anyway to compute total overlapped time between groups by comparing all the time intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df %<>% mutate( interval = interval( start_time, end_time ) )

df %>% full_join( df, by=character(), suffix=c("_1","_2") ) %>%
    mutate( overlap = lubridate::intersect( interval_1, interval_2 ) ) %>%
    filter( id_1 < id_2 ) %>%
    replace_na( list(overlap=0) ) %>%
    group_by( id_1, id_2 ) %>%
    summarise( overlap = paste(paste( as.numeric( overlap ) / 60, collapse=" + " ),"mins"))
```

various lubridate functions are key to the solution, the rest is just infrastructure

Output:

```
  id_1  id_2  overlap              
  <chr> <chr> <chr>                
1 a     b     0 + 60 mins          
2 a     c     10 + 0 + 0 + 30 mins
3 b     c     0 + 60 mins
```

Comment: note, there's likely a typo in your input data, it says 2015 on row 2 end_time, should surely be 2016

Comment: Thank you for such a great answer and finding the typo! I correct the typo. I struggled with it since I was not familiar with lubridate functions. What I actually asked for the last column was to get the sum of the values, but I think I can handle it. Thank you @Sirius !

Comment: While I was running the code, I got an error message saying "Error: `by` must specify variables to join by." Did I miss something in the code?

Comment: Might have to update dplyr to allow joining on an empty character(), which is key here

Comment: Thank you for the quick and exactly right comment for the question. I fixed the issue!